# Can we use asset html files in Alert dialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, about-box

Currently i am using string to show text in alert dialog , is there a way to use assets html file directly without using layout and show alert dialog like this code

```
 private void About() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.about));
    alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.stringabout));
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,
            getString(R.string.lbl_dialog_close),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   close
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: u can use but for this coustem dailog box with webview that webview load html file

Comment: Sorry but i see nothing which refers to assets. And i do not see where you want to use content from an assets file. Please be exact.

Comment: @Naveen How can you please show me a example

Comment: @greenapps I just given a code which i am using now and showing text from strings .

Comment: @Cervo Have u know Custeam Dailog in android

Comment: That i see ofcourse. But where do you want to use text from a html file?

Comment: @greenapps i am asking if it is possible to use html asset files by modifying this code

Comment: Please be exact. Come to the point.

Comment: @greenapps i want to remove strings and want to use html file only

Comment: @Moradiya Akash i am just showing text from strings and not using any text view or layout . in your suggested code i see this TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(text); which i don't understand

Comment: Who suggested that code? And you still did not tell for what you want to use text from a html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way,

```
 try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourhtmlfile.txt");

            // We guarantee that the available method returns the total
            // size of the asset...  of course, this does mean that a single
            // asset can't be more than 2 gigs.
            int size = is.available();

            // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();

            // Convert the buffer into a string.
            String text = new String(buffer);

            // Finally stick the string into the text view.
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Should never happen!
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Comment: i am just showing text from strings and not using any text view or layout . in your suggested code i see this TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            tv.setText(text); which i don't understand